# what is the role of 0 as initalValue for reduce function?

Tags: javascript, reduce

to learn `reduce` function I experimented with this [w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_reduce2)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get the sum of the rounded numbers in the array.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p>Sum of numbers in array: <span id="demo"></span></p>

<script>
var numbers = [15.5, 2.3, 1.1, 4.7];

function getSum(total, num) {
  return total + Math.round(num);
}
function myFunction(item) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum, 0);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this example if we pass 0 for `initalValue` it returns 24 but if we use its default `initalValue`, the result would be 23.5!
So I can't get the point of zero and why it changes the result! isn't `initialValue` equal to 0 already?

Comment: Like pointed out, initial value will equal first element that is NOT rounded,.  When you use 0, the first element will then get rounded,.  And this is the reason for the different values  23.5 & 24.  Using without an initial value does have slight performance advantage, but as seen the way your doing it, can have side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**. The initial value of the `accumulator` is the first element in the `array` and it starts from second element until explicitly a value is given to the `accumulator`(0 in this case). When no value was given, `accumulator` was already 15.5 in the beginning but when you gave it value `0`, it started from there hence the difference in results.

> The first time the callback is called, accumulator and currentValue
>   can be one of two values. If initialValue is provided in the call to
>   reduce(), then accumulator will be equal to initialValue, and
>   currentValue will be equal to the first value in the array. If no
>   initialValue is provided, then accumulator will be equal to the first
>   value in the array, and currentValue will be equal to the second.
>
> Note: If initialValue isn't provided, reduce() will execute the
>   callback function starting at index 1, skipping the first index. If
>   initialValue is provided, it will start at index 0.

Refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Quote text **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 0):

> If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will
>   be used. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initial value
>   is an error.

So you have `15.5` as initial value if you don't use 0

You can read here for more info  --> [Reduce Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters)

For example you can see this code if you see since we have 0.1 at start so it is taken as initial value.

```js
let arr = [0.1,15.5, 2.3, 1.1, 4.7]

let output = arr.reduce((op, cur) => op+=Math.round(cur) )

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

If initial value is 0, then all sums returned by getSum are integer, the first computation is 0 + Math.round(15.5) = 16. Futher summands are all integers because of they are added using Math.round. That is why the final result is integer (24).
If initial value is ungiven, the first sum computed by getSum is 15.5 + Math.round(2.3) = 17.5. Futher computations are all done with a first, not rounded summand that is not an integer but has a decimal part of 0.5. So the final result is not an integer.
It may help to put

```
console.log("add "+total+"  +  "+num+" => "+Math.round(num)+"  =  "+(total + Math.round(num)));
```

as the first line in the getSum function and see the console output (F12 on Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

initialValue(Optional) - Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. 
1. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. 
2. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initial value is an error. 
(refer mdn)

As per 1st statement if no initial value is used first element will be used, so in this array [15.5, 2.3, 1.1, 4.7], first element is used as initial value, because of which math.round() is not applied on initial value(15.5).

A. So with 0 the input for reduce function is - 0 + 16 + 2 + 1 +5 = 24
B. Without 0 the input is - 15.5 + 2 + 1 + 5 = 23.5

So interpreting 1st and 2nd statement, if you want to do some operation on the inputs (like Math etc...), you have to provide desired initial value(like 0 in the above case).